# Prove ${a^2+ac-c^2=b^2+bd-d^2}$ and $a > b > c > d \implies ab + cd$ is not prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, complex-numbers

Let $a>b>c>d$ be positive integers and suppose that
$${a^2+ac-c^2=b^2+bd-d^2}$$

Prove that $ab+cd$ is not prime? I don't know if this problem is true.

I found that this same problem has also been posted on [AOPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=119217&sid=27dfe4d374dd651d60ca8014e1bbec03#p119217).

But I can't prove this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why complex-numbers ?

Comment: Your version does not match the problem on AOPS which you refer to.

Comment: That's supposed to be $ac+bd=(b+d+a-c)(b+d-a+c)\implies {a^2-ac+c^2=b^2+bd+d^2}$

Comment: @nikita2: Complex numbers can be used.

Comment: @Math110: I have edited the question. Have a look if I have made some error in that. And make sure of answering your own question if you're done with that. Community appreciates that.:)

Comment: @Inceptio: Surely if you believe you can correct OP's question based on comparison with the AOPS link, then the statement there is clearer (less obfuscated).  On the other hand if the OP asked what they meant to ask, replacing it with a different question is not helpful.  Perhaps we should wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: @hardmath: I have asked OP to clarify. And he has mentioned clearly with the link that he isn't able to solve that particular question, so there **MIGHT** be a typo. But still, its up to OP to accept the edit.

Comment: No, the $IMO42$ I can solve, But my problem,I don't have prove it.

Comment: @math110 by the way, I've noticed that you haven't accepted any an answer to any of your question. do accept those answers which you think are correct - I'm sure a number of them are!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite as:

$$a^2-b^2+ac-bc=bd-bc+c^2-d^2$$
$$(a-b)(a+b+c)=(c-d)(c+d-b)$$

Since $a>b>c>d$, each of $a-b, a+b+c, c-d, c+d-b$ is positive. By [factoring lemma](https://web.archive.org/web/20110725040723/https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-content/uploads/reflections/2007_6/factoring_lemma.pdf) (excerpted below) there exists $w, x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ s.t.

$$a-b=wx, a+b+c=yz, c-d=wy, c+d-b=xz$$

Solving for $a, b, c, d$, we get:

\begin{align}
5a=3wx+2yz-wy-xz \\
5b=-2wx+2yz-wy-xz \\
5c=-wx+yz+2wy+2xz \\
5d=-wx+yz-3wy+2xz
\end{align}

Thus:

\begin{align}
& 25(ab+cd) \\
& =(3wx+2yz-wy-xz)(-2wx+2yz-wy-xz) \\
& +(-wx+yz+2wy+2xz)(-wx+yz-3wy+2xz) \\
& =5(z^2-wz-w^2)(x^2+y^2)
\end{align}

$$5(ab+cd)=(z^2-wz-w^2)(x^2+y^2)$$

Since $b>c$,

$$-2wx+2yz-wy-xz=5b>5c=-wx+yz+2wy+2xz$$
$$yz>wx+3wy+3xz$$

In particular, $yz>wx+3wy+3xz>3xz$ implies $y>3x$ and $yz>wx+3wy+3xz>3wy$ implies $z>3w$.

Thus
$$x^2+y^2>x^2+9x^2>5$$
$$z^2-wz-w^2=(z-\frac{w}{2})^2-\frac{5w^2}{4}>(3w-\frac{w}{2})^2-\frac{5w^2}{4}=5w^2 \geq 5$$

If $ab+cd$ is a prime, then $ab+cd \geq 4(3)+2(1)>5$, then $5(ab+cd)=(z^2-wz-w^2)(x^2+y^2)$ implies that $ab+cd$ divides exactly 1 of $z^2-wz-w^2$ and $x^2+y^2$. However, the term not divisible by $ab+cd$ must necessarily divide $5$, and thus be $\leq 5$. Since both $z^2-wz-w^2>5$ and $x^2+y^2>5$, we obtain a contradiction.

Therefore $ab+cd$ is not prime.

---

Below is the linked "factoring lemma".

[image]

Comment: oh,It's very nice!Thank you very much.

Comment: That was good. +1

Comment: @Ivan Loh a small typo in the line above "Since b>c" :)

Comment: @VincentTjeng Fixed.

Comment: is there any other way to solve given problem because in your solution it quite tedious too solve those four equation to get value of $a,b,c,d$ Also link provided by you is not working

Comment: @mathophile I updated the link, and added an excerpt. The "factoring Lemma $1$" is better known as **Euler's Four Number Theorem**. It is one of many well-known properties that are equivalent to the *uniqueness* of prime factorizations, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3835192/242) and its links.

Answer (score 2):

The key observation is:

$$ (ac-bd) ( a^2 + ac - c^2) =  (ab+cd) ( bc - ad). $$

This can be shown by expanding the LHS as $(ac)(b^2+bd-d^2) - (bd) (a^2 + ac - c^2)$, noticing that $abcd$ cancels out, and factoring.

Proof by contradiction. Suppose $ab+cd$ is prime.

- Because $ac-bd > 0, a^2+ac-c^2 > 0, ab+cd > 0,$ hence we can conclude that $bc-ad > 0$.
- Since $0 < ac - bd < ab + cd$, so $\gcd(ac-bd, ab+cd) = 1$, hence $ ac-bd \mid bc-ad$.
- This implies that $ ac-bd \leq bc-ad$.
- However, $(a-b)(c+d) > 0  \Leftrightarrow ac - bd > bc  - ad $.

We have a contradiction, so $ ab+cd$ is not prime.

---

Notes

I came up with the key observation because I was working on similar problems like

1. IMO 2001/6,
2. [If $a^2+ab+b^2 = c^2 + cd+d^2$, then $a+b+c+d$ is not prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466815/a2-b2-ab-c2-d2-cd-is-it-possible-that-abcd-be-prime/4185638#4185638),   and
3. If $ a>b>c >d > 0 $ such that $a^2-ab+b^2 = c^2 - cd + d^2 $ then $ ab+cd $ is not prime.

In all of them, there's an approach that similarly finds a nice algebraic expression involving the variables, then argues about primality.