# Let $a,b,c,d\in N$ and in strictly increasing order such that $b^2-bd-d^2=a^2-ac-c^2$. Prove that $ab+cd$ is not a prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, alternative-proof

> Let $a,b,c,d\in N$ and in strictly increasing order such that $$b^2-bd-d^2=a^2-ac-c^2$$ Prove that $ab+cd$ is not a prime.

**Approach:** $c^2-d^2-bd=a^2-b^2-ac$

$\implies  c^2-d^2-bd=a^2-b^2-ac+bc-bc$

$\implies c^2-d^2-bd=(a+b)(a-b)-c(a-b)-bc$

$\implies c^2-d^2-bd+bc=(a+b)(a-b)-c(a-b)$

$\implies c^2-d^2-bd+bc=(a-b)(a+b-c)$

$\implies (c+d)(c-d)+b(c-d)=(a-b)(a+b-c)$

$\implies (c+d+b)(c-d)=(a-b)(a+b-c)$

How to processed further.?

This question is similar to **[Prove ${a^2+ac-c^2=b^2+bd-d^2}$ and $a > b > c > d \implies ab + cd$ is not prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342504/prove-a2ac-c2-b2bd-d2-and-a-b-c-d-implies-ab-cd-is-not-prim)** But he used factoring lemma and provided link but that link is not working.

**Can you show me how to do that?**

**Is there other method too to solve this problem?**

Comment: I updated the linked answer to include the cited Lemma

Comment: The "factoring Lemma" is better known as **Euler's Four Number Theorem**. It is one of many well-known properties that are equivalent to the *uniqueness* of prime factorizations, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3835192/242) and its links.

Comment: took me a while to find any with distinct integers; common target $-6061,$  pairs $ (43,70); (51,71); (61,73); (63, 74) $ for six ordered quadruples such as $(43,51, 70,71)$

Comment: pathfinder for Olympiad mathematics

Comment: Given that $ a  < b < c < d$, we have $ d^2 + bd  - b^2 = c^2 + ca  - a^2$ with $ d > c > b > a $. Hence, it's identical to the linked solution, using the change of variables $ a \rightarrow d, b \rightarrow c, c \rightarrow b, d \rightarrow a$, so I'm voting to close as duplicate. FYI I added a nice short solution.

Answer (score 1):

This works if $a>b>c>d>0$.

Write $p= ab+cd$ and assume $p$ is prime.
Then plug in $a = (p-cd)/b$ and we get: $$\boxed{p(ab-cd-bc) =
(b^2+c^2)(b^2-bd-d^2)}$$ and if we plug $c= (p-ab)/d$ we get
$$\boxed{p(ab-cd-ad) =
(a^2+d^2)(b^2-bd-d^2)}$$

1. If $p\mid b^2-bd-d^2$

   - If $b^2-bd-d^2 \geq 0$ then $ab+cd \leq b^2 -bd
     -d^2<b^2<ab$ a contradiction.
   - If $b^2-bd-d^2 < 0$ then $ab+cd \leq d^2+bd -b^2 
      <d^2+bd <ab +cd$ a contradiction.
2. If $p\nmid b^2-bd-d^2$, then $p\mid a^2+d^2$ and $p\mid
   b^2+c^2$ so $$p^2\mid (a^2+d^2)(b^2+c^2) = (ab+cd)^2
   +(ac-bd)^2$$
   and thus $$p^2\mid (ac-bd)^2\implies p\mid ac-bd \implies
   ab+cd\leq ac-bd< ac<ab$$
   A  contradiction again. So $p$ can not be prime.

Comment: $d^2<cd$ and $ db<ab$ @WillJagy

Comment: the first sentce of the question reads $0 < a < b < c < d $ because they are natural numbers "in strictly increasing order"

Comment: Well I thought it is another way around.

Comment: Check out my solution in the linked question. There's a strong similarity with what you're doing. In fact, from your first 2 equations, we get $ (ab+cd)(cd - ad) = (a^2 + d^2 - b^2 - c^2 ) (b^2 - bd - d^2 ) = (ac-bd ) (b^2 - bd - d^2)$, which is what I used. (Was trying to see if I could patch your solution.)